# Use d3 in an commonjs npm module

Tags: javascript, d3.js, commonjs, esmodules

I am creating a private npm package to visualize the structure of a Vuejs project. d3 seems to be on of the best choices for a visualization, but I have problems to include it in my script. In the `package.json` I defined my script under the `bin` property `"bin": {  "visualize": "vis.js" },` and imported d3 (as I have seen other projects also did it this way)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var d3 = require('d3');`.
```

But then I get the following error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: <Project Path>\node_modules\d3\src\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.`
```

So I changed it to `var d3 = import('d3');` it works, but then the statement `var d3tree = d3.tree()` raises `TypeError: d3.tree is not a function`

Is it even possible to use d3 in commonjs? Or maybe there is another graph visualization library which works directly.

Answer (score 1):

`import('d3')` [dynamically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) loads `d3` which you should wait for to be ready.

```
import('d3').then(d3 => {
     // use d3 here
});
```

Another choice is to migrate your project from commonjs to ESM.